# How to get current logged in user from EzPlatform 1.1 to symfony class code using php?

Tags: php, symfony, ezplatform

I'm developing web application with symfony and also using EzPlatform as Cms for the same project. Would like to get the current logged in user from EzPlatform to my symfony controller using php.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the Symfony user, you can get it from token storage service (`@security.token_storage`):

```
$sfUser = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
```

Once you have the Symfony user, you can get eZ Platform user with:

```
$eZUser = $sfUser->getAPIUser();
```

There is also a method called `getCurrentUser` on eZ repository (`@ezpublish.api.repository` service) with which you can get the current user directly:

```
$eZUser = $repository->getCurrentUser();
```

Comment: Thank you! was able to do it with: $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

Comment: Would like to accept it but my reputations is too low to do that. Need more votes up :)